# Ubuntu 16.04: Can't manually mount a partition i've freshly created with fdisk

Tags: partitioning, mount

I've created a BigBlueButton server on Ubuntu 16.04 and it's running great. However I want to use a secondary hard drive and I am having trouble mounting a partition I just created for video storage.

Running fdisk gives me my primary boot HDD and then this is the second HDD:

bbb@BBB:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
[sudo] password for bbb: 
Disk /dev/sda: 465.7 GiB, 500074307584 bytes, 976707632 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x9d2985aa

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 974706687 974704640 464.8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       974708734 976705535   1996802   975M  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       974708736 976705535   1996800   975M 82 Linux swap / Solaris

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1.4 TiB, 1500222873600 bytes, 2930122800 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0233a030

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 2930122799 2930120752  1.4T 83 Linux
```

Here's extra info:

```
sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sdb    ext4     1.4T            
└─sdb1 ext4     1.4T            
sda           465.7G            
├─sda2            1K            
├─sda5 swap     975M [SWAP]     
└─sda1 ext4   464.8G /
```

I created a mount point:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/RAIDStorage
```

Then tried to mount to it:

```
sudo mount -t auto -v /dev/sdb1 /mnt/RAIDStorage
```

I get the error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

dmesg | tail gives me:

```
[17246.250401] perf: interrupt took too long (8816 > 8608), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 22500
[185227.798264]  sdb: sdb1
[412747.752543] ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[442833.441887]  sdb: sdb1
[442936.706648]  sdb:
[442936.715148]  sdb:
[443148.384028]  sdb: sdb1
[444753.363305] EXT4-fs (sdb1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[444888.723804] EXT4-fs (sdb1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[445286.327651]  sdb: sdb1
```

I was wondering if formatting the main drive itself as ext4 was causing issues. I couldn't any way to undo that, all searched only references the partitions themselves. Any help is appreciated, I am newer at linux.  Thank you!

Edit:

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
    Disk /dev/sda: 465.7 GiB, 500074307584 bytes, 976707632 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disklabel type: dos
    Disk identifier: 0x9d2985aa

    Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
    /dev/sda1  *         2048 974706687 974704640 464.8G 83 Linux
    /dev/sda2       974708734 976705535   1996802   975M  5 Extended
    /dev/sda5       974708736 976705535   1996800   975M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Comment: If the disk is clear, try to reformat it again into ext4 - mkfs.ext4

Comment: I just ran mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb  again and then created a partition and tried to remount - and unfortunately failed and got the same dmesg | tail output.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` and screenshots of `gparted` for both sda and sdb. Why is sdb in MBR format? What kind of partition did you create on sdb1?

Comment: I added the results for my main drive. There's no requirement for MBR as far as I know, how would I format it to GPT if you recommend that? And to create the partition I run: sudo fdisk /dev/sdb then "N", then I hit enter for all defaults, then W to save. Thanks for your help!